# Mathematica returns unsolved integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following integral:

```
Integrate[x^2*(0.8400759670307388*u^2*(1 - x^2/64)^0.5*Sin[99.08073128263472/u^2]*
   (99.08073128263472/u^2 + 0.00021774529335553323*x + x*phi[t] + 
     (0.8999999999999999 - 0.03749999999999999*x)*x*Derivative[1][phi][t])^2 + 
  Cos[99.08073128263472/u^2]*(2.3970351946890123*u*((-3.515400000000001*u^2*rb[t])/
       (-24.000000000000004 + 1.*x) - (3.515400000000001*u^2*x*rp[t])/(-24.000000000000004 + 1.*x) - 
      (3.515400000000001*u^2*x^2*rw[t])/(-24.000000000000004 + 1.*x) - 0.786*u*Derivative[1][rb][t] - 
      0.786*u*x*Derivative[1][rp][t] - 0.786*u*x^2*Derivative[1][rw][t] - 
      0.024999999999999994*(-24.000000000000004 + 1.*x)*Derivative[2][rb][t] - 
      0.024999999999999994*x*(-24.000000000000004 + 1.*x)*Derivative[2][rp][t] - 
      0.024999999999999994*x^2*(-24.000000000000004 + 1.*x)*Derivative[2][rw][t]) + 
    0.5992587986722531*(1.2 - 0.04999999999999999*x)^2*x*(u*Derivative[1][phi][t] + 
      (0.3 - 0.012499999999999997*x)*Derivative[2][phi][t] - x*Derivative[2][w][t]))),{x,0,8}]
```

Yet Mathematica returns the integral itself. Why is so? If I ask Mathematica to integrate the integrand without the factor x^2, it works. Why does it not work with the complete integrand?

Comment: Apply ExpandAll to the integrand. This helps.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18485#18485

Comment: I must say I don't see fundamentally why the floats should cause this to fail ( fixing the one real exponent to `1/2` doesn't help )

Comment: @george2079 But `Rationalize[f, 0]` does work. I've noticed that exact solvers have improved in their ability to handle inexact input, esp. `Solve`/`NSolve`, but I got to think that rounding error in internal transformations performed by `Integrate` are going to sometimes, even if not always, cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your over-accurate numbers are one reason. 
One solution, is to [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), and [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) your equation.

```
equ=Chop[equ,10^-9];
equ=Rationalize[equ,10^-9];
Integrate[equ,{x,0,8}]
```

This produces a solution. I will skip entering it here since it's not very small.

Another possibility, is using [`ExpandAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html) like pointed out [in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129620/mathematica-returns-unsolved-integral#comment350198_129620).

```
Integrate[ExpandAll[equ], {x, 0, 8}]
```

They seem to produce the same result though (try apply N to the first).